# wpa_supplicant not connecting, because SSL3 is unsupported

Tags: debian, openssl, wpa-supplicant

I've a laptop running Debian GNU/Linux Unstable with Network Manager. Since an update of OpenSSL (1.1.1 I think), I can't connect to a Wi-Fi network using WPA2 Enterprise with PEAP (MSCHAPv2). In `/var/log/syslog`, it says that SSL3 is unsupported:

```
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with [REDACTED] (SSID='Hotspot' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.195724] wlp4s0: authenticate with [REDACTED]
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 NetworkManager[505]: <info>  [1540893138.8304] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.216389] wlp4s0: send auth to [REDACTED] (try 1/3)
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.218779] wlp4s0: authenticated
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with [REDACTED] (SSID='Hotspot' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.228045] wlp4s0: associate with [REDACTED] (try 1/3)
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.233930] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from [REDACTED] (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.234023] wlp4s0: associated
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: Associated with [REDACTED]
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 NetworkManager[505]: <info>  [1540893138.8600] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 NetworkManager[505]: <info>  [1540893138.8605] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=NL
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259127] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8210
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259130] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259131] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259132] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259133] ath: Country alpha2 being used: NL
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259134] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 kernel: [    9.259136] ath: regdomain 0x8210 dynamically updated by country element
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:protocol version
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
Oct 30 10:52:18 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct 30 10:52:20 wb9688-b50 kernel: [   11.335881] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from [REDACTED] by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct 30 10:52:20 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: Authentication with [REDACTED] timed out.
Oct 30 10:52:21 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=[REDACTED] reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct 30 10:52:21 wb9688-b50 wpa_supplicant[502]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Hotspot" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct 30 10:52:21 wb9688-b50 NetworkManager[505]: <warn>  [1540893141.3677] sup-iface[0x5617eb7458b0,wlp4s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 30 10:52:21 wb9688-b50 NetworkManager[505]: <info>  [1540893141.3704] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
```

Downgrading OpenSSL fixes it of course, but then I can't use things that are compiled to newer versions of OpenSSL. Is there any way to connect to the Wi-Fi network?

Comment: If the RADIUS server does not support (newer) versions of TLS, that is not a Unix problem. However, you are able to get way using multiple versions of the SSL libraries (not mutiple versions of the OpenSSL binary per se)

Comment: see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Why would that question be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911389 seems to be relevant.  It suggests editing the last two lines in `/etc/ssl/openssl.conf`.  Be sure to use TLSv1.0, that is what worked in my horrible MS AD installation.

Obviously, one should ask the friendly SysAdmin to cease using proprietary software, or at least to accept newer protocol versions.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work if I change it to allow TLS v1.0, but I should probably talk to the network admin to update the RADIUS server so that it support TLS v1.2.

Comment: Yes, that value worked for me too.  I was trying to be too smart and put TLSv1 there.  Please accept my answer then!  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To extend the answer for users of other Linux distributions, the following can help to solve this problem in Fedora 33:

```
sudo dnf install crypto-policies-scripts
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

wpa_supplicant daemon needs to be restarted after the change:

```
systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
```

To restore default configuation, use

```
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

on my ubuntu 22.04

```
Apr 23 10:41:31 thomas-laptop wpa_supplicant[3116]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:internal error
Apr 23 10:41:31 thomas-laptop wpa_supplicant[3116]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error
Apr 23 10:41:32 thomas-laptop wpa_supplicant[3116]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
```

```
cat ~/temp/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=root
ap_scan=0
network={
  key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
  eap=PEAP
  phase1="peaplabel=auto tls_disable_tlsv1_0=0 tls_disable_tlsv1_1=0 tls_disable_tlsv1_2=0 tls_ext_cert_check=0"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  identity="yourusername"
  password="yourpassword"
  eapol_flags=0
}

sudo wpa_supplicant -f ~/temp/wpa.log -dd -c wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwired -ieth0
sudo dhclient eth0
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wpa_supplicant

archlinux is a great linux.