# CentOS Stream 9 "SSL_Connect error: unsupported protocol" when connecting to wpa2enterperise wifi

Tags: centos, wifi

Hello fellow CentOS users. I'm using CentOS Stream 9 and I have a problem connecting to my University's WIFI, which uses WPA2 Enterprise, any other connection works fine. I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad T460 with Intel Wireless adapter.

**Error seems to be this specicifally:**

```
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:protocol version
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
```

If you need full logs, here are the messages from `journalctl -f`

```
May 06 07:45:10 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:49:06 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:49:06 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:49:16 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:49:16 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:50:27 localhost.localdomain sudo[34290]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 06 07:51:53 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:51:53 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:53:50 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:53:50 localhost.localdomain rtkit-daemon[816]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.5091] device (wlp4s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.5094] device (wlp4s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.5098] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.5111] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="8cda2dc7-b805-4580-bbef-b65d1d362b8d" name="SDU_WiFi" pid=2407 uid=1000 result="success"
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 96:7b:b7:05:80:40 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=96:7b:b7:05:80:40 reason=3 locally_generated=1
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6040] device (wlp4s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d1bd:58d9:fda9:461d on wlp4s0.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d1bd:58d9:fda9:461d.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6116] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6117] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6117] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed no lease
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain gnome-shell[2407]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.250.58.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.250.58 on wlp4s0.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6248] device (wlp4s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 06:6F:C3:AD:61:32 (scanning)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.250.58.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: New relevant interface wlp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Registering new address record for 192.168.250.58 on wlp4s0.IPv4.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.250.58 on wlp4s0.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.250.58.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[806]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6485] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6495] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'SDU_WiFi' (8cda2dc7-b805-4580-bbef-b65d1d362b8d)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6504] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6504] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6508] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6508] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6509] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6509] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6527] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.6533] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain chronyd[852]: Source 45.132.84.104 offline
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain chronyd[852]: Source 185.116.194.200 offline
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain chronyd[852]: Source 185.121.81.200 offline
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain chronyd[852]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain chronyd[852]: Source 213.157.40.210 offline
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8827] device (wlp4s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to E4:B3:18:F5:65:31 (preserve)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8898] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8915] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SDU_WiFi' has security, but secrets are required.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8916] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8945] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.8947] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9018] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9019] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9023] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9041] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9058] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SDU_WiFi' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9059] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SDU_WiFi'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9060] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9061] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9063] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9063] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9064] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9065] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9066] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9068] Config: added 'identity' value '200103403'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9069] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (SSID='SDU_WiFi' freq=2462 MHz)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: authenticate with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: send auth to 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (try 1/3)
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9377] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 06 07:56:52 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374212.9378] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: send auth to 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (try 2/3)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (SSID='SDU_WiFi' freq=2462 MHz)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: authenticated
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: associate with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (try 1/3)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.1050] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.1052] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: associate with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (try 2/3)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: associated
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: Associated with 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.2352] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.2354] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:protocol version
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: deauthenticated from 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d (Reason: 23=IEEE8021X_FAILED)
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=78:45:58:dc:a4:2d reason=23
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="SDU_WiFi" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: BSSID 78:45:58:dc:a4:2d ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.3551] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.3553] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.4549] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 06 07:56:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374213.4551] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 06 07:57:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="SDU_WiFi"
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (SSID='SDU_WiFi' freq=2437 MHz)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: authenticate with d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: send auth to d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (try 1/3)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.4909] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.4912] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (SSID='SDU_WiFi' freq=2437 MHz)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: authenticated
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: associate with d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (try 1/3)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.4968] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.4969] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=6)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: Associated with d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: associated
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.5176] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.5177] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:protocol version
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp4s0: deauthenticated from d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e (Reason: 23=IEEE8021X_FAILED)
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e reason=23
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="SDU_WiFi" auth_failures=2 duration=38 reason=AUTH_FAILED
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[34108]: BSSID d0:21:f9:55:a0:1e ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.7327] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.7328] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.8312] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 06 07:57:06 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[971]: <info>  [1683374226.8314] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
```

looked the error up through the forums, the Fedora ones suggested `sudo update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY` which for some reason did not work in my case (neither that worked when I was using Tumbleweed for some reason), yet it worked in Fedora 38 when I tested it in LiveCD. Since Fedora is an upstream of CentOS Stream I wonder what kind of patches they made specifically to solve this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In Centos 9, the older version of tls disabled default, even you use the legacy mode. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/securing_networks/planning-and-implementing-tls_securing-networks
You may enable the old tls in the wpa config file. (Sorry, I don't know where is it in centos 9)

Comment: Anyway, if you can, tell the administrators, need to upgrade the wifi system.

Comment: @K-att- if that's true, shouldn't that also be true for Fedora, where it works?

Comment: "In RHEL 9, TLS configuration is performed using the system-wide cryptographic policies mechanism. TLS versions below 1.2 are not supported anymore. DEFAULT, FUTURE, and LEGACY cryptographic policies allow only TLS 1.2 and 1.3. See Using system-wide cryptographic policies for more information."

Comment: @K-att- ok, saw the info in the docs, seems like I have to get other methods of solving this.

Comment: The keyword: system-wide (that's why the legacy not worked for you). You can use the tls_1.0 if you set it in the wpa config file, I think.

Comment: Hint: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478668/wpa-supplicant-not-connecting-because-ssl3-is-unsupported

Comment: @K-att- I've seen that post before, it edits the system config/ and even then it does not solve the issue

Comment: The 3rd answer. 
"phase1="peaplabel=auto tls_disable_tlsv1_0=0 tls_disable_tlsv1_1=0 tls_disable_tlsv1_2=0 tls_ext_cert_check=0"

Comment: @K-att- where do I need to write this?